# Query to conditionally distribute rows to column

Tags: mysql, oracle

Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 , working with Oracle SQL Developer

> TableA - Key1 - Key2 - ConditionColumn
>
> **TA - K1 - K2 - C1**

**Query-1
`SELECT K1, K2 FROM TA WHERE C1 = 1234 ORDER BY K1;`**

`--K1   K2
--T40105    136853
--T40108    136861
--T40109    136869
--T40111    136878
--T40113    136886`

> TableB - Key2 - Data1 - Data2
>
> **TB - K2 - D1 - D2**

**Query-2
`SELECT K2, D1, D2 FROM TB WHERE K2 = (SELECT K2 FROM TA WHERE K1='T40105');`**

`--K2   D1  D2
--136853    1   1554
--136853    2   1552
--136853    3   1552`

D1 is always = {1, 2, 3} for specific Key2. 
**How to combine these 2 Queries to get output as shown below for all values of K1?**

`--K1       K2      D2(@D1=1)   D2(@D1=2)   D2(@D1=3) 
--T40105    136853  1554        1552        1552
--T40108    136861 
--T40109    136869
--T40111    136878
--T40113    136886`

Answer (score 0):

i have tried with below code

```
select * from
(select a.k1,a.k2,b.d2,b.d1 from ta  a
left outer join
tb b
on a.k2=b.k2
)
pivot(sum(d2) as d  for (d1) in (1,2,3))
order by k1
```

Comment: "Pivot" is not working ERROR: "SQL command not properly ended". I am using 10g, Google says "Pivot" is for 11g

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution (Oracle 10g)**

```
SELECT MAX(h.K1) AS "K1"
,b.K1 AS "K2"
,SUM(DECODE(D1,1,D2)) AS "D2(D1=1)"
,SUM(DECODE(D1,2,D2)) AS "D2(D1=2)"
,SUM(DECODE(D1,3,D2)) AS "D2(D1=3)"
FROM TB b RIGHT OUTER JOIN TA h on h.K1 = b.K1
WHERE C1 = 1234
GROUP BY b.K2
ORDER BY b.K2;
```